# what is ME disable switch?

Tags: 18.04

Just installed 18.04. It's asking me about this every time I log on. It has something to do with security and passwords, but I can't find a definition. I can't decide what to do with it if I don't know what it is.

Comment: What is the exact message?

Comment: We need more information, but I might venture a guess that it has something to do with the Intel Management Engine?

Comment: Sounds like something to ask the hardware manufacturer about. What is the exact hardware?

Comment: @waltinator System76 Oryx Pro laptop, 64bit, 16 RAM, Intel Core i7-7700 HQ, 2.8GHzx8. @ survivalmachine I'll reboot to get the message

Comment: @survivalmachine  After I log in, a small window appears that says "New firmware available, Add ME disable switch?" When I hover on it, the bottom extends and allows me to click "Install firmware"

Answer (score 1):

System 76 offers you the ability to [disable the Intel Management Engine](https://blog.system76.com/post/168050597573/system76-me-firmware-updates-plan), a computer-within-your-computer. However, if you change your OS to a different release or version, IME may return.

Some folks [don't like IME for security reasons](https://www.wired.com/story/intel-management-engine-vulnerabilities-pcs-servers-iot/). Suggest you do your own research on the benefits and downsides of IME before you make a decision.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, I searched for "system76 me disable switch" and found that it's System76's solution to a security problem with Intel's management engine.

https://archive.is/ccpeg

One discussion seems to indicate that it's not actually disabled.

https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/hardware/motherboards-chipsets/992601-system76-will-begin-disabling-intel-me-in-their-linux-laptops/page4

I don't know if that's the whole story, but I've identified the issue to research.